# How to recover file changes discarded with fugitive_X in the fugitive summary buffer?

Tags: git, plugin-fugitive

In the fugitive summary buffer, the powerful `X` command does as explained in `:help fugitive_X`:

> Discard the change under the cursor.  This uses `checkout` or `clean` under the
> hood.  A command is echoed that shows how to undo the change.  Consult
> `:messages` to see it again.  You can use this during a merge conflict do
> discard "our" changes (--theirs) in the "Unstaged" section or discard "their"
> changes (--ours) in the "Staged" section.

I used `X` mistakenly then closed Vim because I was in a hurry. I had 5 changed files in the repository and I'm a bit sad to have lost those changes. It's a note taking repository with the effort of a few days (I know I should have committed earlier, it's not my main work, just notes on the side). A help hint in the message bar says to use the following to recover one file. I tested and managed to recover it.

```
:Gsplit art/music.md|Gread 124cdf331a4
```

Can I recover the other files checked out before that test? I didn't see the message back then and `:message` only prints message for the active vim session.  How do I find out about fugitive messages printed in previous sessions? What are those hash numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost certainly lost the `:messages`. I am not aware of any builtin messages persistence.

However, *if* fugitive or git managed to save the blobs, you could try to find them with `git fsck` (check `--unreachable` or `--dangling`) or else just poking around in the list of blobs (https://stackoverflow.com/q/1595631/4400820). Test each with `git cat-file -p <sha>`; if it is correct, you can `git cat-file blob <sha> >/path/to/the/file` or similar to restore the file.